# Block everyone, except visitors from specific referrer with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, restrict, referer

In htaccess, how can i block every visitor except those who come from a specific domain

i tried this but without any success :

```
# serve everyone from specific-domain or specific-user-agent 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.specific-domain.com 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    
    # everybody else receives a forbidden 
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
    
    ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

Update : i had certain success with below code BUT it broked my webpage certainly because of the following parameters that overrride or disturbe appearance. if someone has a clue how to order it the good way ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://authorizedreferer.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://unprotected.mydomain.com/ [R,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What about requests from your own domain? What about direct requests?

Comment: @MrWhite i am not sure to understand what you propose ?  sorry i am just a beginner in htaccess ;-)

Comment: Forget `.htaccess` for a moment... you need to have a grasp of what's going on with the HTTP requests before you can attempt to implement something in `.htaccess`. Is your site just a single page with no static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.)? If not then when users request a page of your site then your site itself is going to generate a `Referer` header when requesting static assets. Also, what about direct requests and other requests where the `Referer` is not set? Are you OK with blocking these?

Comment: _Aside:_ The second code block you added doesn't make much sense? Are you using a front-controller?

Comment: "i tried this but without any success" - And what specifically do you mean by this? What happens exactly? That first code block should do what you are asking, ie. block all requests, other than when the `Referer` HTTP request header does not start with the stated URL. However, that is probably not all you should be doing (as queried in my first comment above).

Comment: thanks for the information @MrWhite , you are right that first block do the job BUT as i say bellow i encounter a last issue with my CSS broken - it seems it's related to absolute or relative link but i struggle a little to find how i can change it the right way...  i am not very far from success i think ;-)

Comment: "it seems it's related to absolute or relative link" - that would only be the case if you are doing URL-rewriting, but there is no evidence of that here? This also has nothing to do with blocking based on the `HTTP_REFERER`, as you would have had the same problem before? Regarding relative/absolute links and URL rewriting, see [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: the fact is that if i comment in the first block # RewriteRule ^ - [F] my homepage is back with css style BUT the referrer restriction is gone (as you must understand now i have no knowledge to know why ;-) ) @MrWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # serve everyone from specific-domain or specific-user-agent 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.specific-domain.com 
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>
> # everybody else receives a forbidden 
> RewriteRule ^ - [F]
> ```

This will indeed allow requests that link from `specific-domain.com` (ie. this domain is the HTTP `Referer`) and block *everything* else. However, it will also block all requests for your static resources, that originate from *your site*, where *your domain* is the `Referer`. So, you need to also allow requests from your domain.

You should also probably allow an empty `Referer` header. ie. direct requests, when a user types the URL into their browser address bar. Also note that the `Referer` header can be suppressed in other ways depending on the referrer-policy as set by the originating website. The user themselves can also override the `Referer` header, so relying on the `Referer` header is not reliable.

Try the following:

```
# Serve everyone from specific-domain (and internal requests)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

And to allow an empty `Referer`, include an additional condition:

```
# Serve everyone from specific-domain (and internal requests and empty referer) 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Note that you are currently allowing `http` or `https` in the `Referer`. If this is always `https` then be specific and remove the `?` (optional quantifier). ie. `^https://www\.specific-domain\.com/`. And remember to backslash escape the literal dots.

Comment: It works perfectly well...Thanks a lot, if you have a little more time to spare me i would be interested on how easy it is to override the referrer header for any user?  what kind of knowledge does it imply just to evaluate the reliability of such a solution.

Comment: A user can install a browser extension to override/fake the `Referer` header. A website/user could write a script to make HTTP requests and fake the `Referer`. The _referrer-policy_ does not permit the `Referer` to be "faked" (ie. set to _anything_), but it can be suppressed. So, if you did allow an empty `Referer`, then other websites would have access simply setting a strict referrer-policy. But legitimate users might also suppress the `Referer`. So, if you block an empty `Referer` you might also block legitimate users.

Comment: @MrWhite sorry to bother you again but i found an issue i don't understand using your solution : when trying to access a typical URL (https://yourdomain.com/page) inside my website i found that i can access it with no restriction ? is it because i didn't set the empty referer ? or because the "page" has no extension like html? if you have hint ? thanks

Comment: "inside my website" - Do you mean when you follow an internal link on your site to another page on your site? Or when you type the URL directly into the browser address bar? But yes, both those requests will be permitted by the rules above, as explained in my answer.

Comment: You could restrict this further and only permit your-domain as the `Referer` when requesting static resources - but this will prevent users from navigating your site, if that is a requirement (unless you set a cookie or something). Or don't allow an empty `Referer` to prevent direct requests (first example) - but the `Referer` header could be blocked by the user, so you'll potentially block legitimate users. To clarify, this doesn't offer any real security as the `Referer` header is unreliable and is easily faked.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for your reply - i do believe from your answer that what i need is to don't allow an empty referer to "prevent" any but the referrer to access any page on my website (ok with the non reliability of it for now) - if i did understood it well, could you please tell me the syntaxe of block any empty referrer as i assume the one you gave me was to allow ?

Comment: @MrWhite i tried to add the following line to try restriction for a single page RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} single-page [NC] but i didn't succeed as it only broke the css style page but still got access being referrer or not..

Comment: "don't allow an empty referer ... i assume the one you gave me was to allow ?" - I gave both in my answer. The first one blocks an empty referer, the second one allows it. "broke the css style" - your pages presumably have JS, CSS and images - these are all separate HTTP requests with their own HTTP `Referer` headers (the `Referer` in this case is always _your domain_).

Comment: @MrWhite i am confuse where is the one which block an empty referrer ? i do see the allow but not the other (sorry bout that) . For the Broken CSS as i did put my domain as a referrer i don't understand why when i directly access the pages (typing url from a private navigation) it doesn't show a forbidden but a broken page instead

Comment: The first code block blocks an empty referer because it does not explicitly allow it. I followed the same pattern of directives that you posted in the question. You allow specific referers and block everything else. "it doesn't show a forbidden but a broken page" - because you are only "seeing" the response from the specific URL you requested. If you look at the network traffic (in the browser dev tools) you will see all the forbidden responses - that is why the page is "broken", the CSS was blocked.

Comment: @MrWhite : ok i got it, but even if the page looks broken i still see url on roll over - is it just a browser cache issue which means a newcomer will have a forbiden message ? or somehow the CSS is blocked but the page still show up for some reason

Comment: You might be seeing a cached response.

Comment: i tried to flush my cache and access from another computer but i got the same - From your point of view would i need to add another rules like RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} page [NC] in order to block access from non referrer OR what you gave me should be enough ? (i mean  the implicite not allow empty referrer should be enough to block for every page of my website ?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit lost of what you are trying to do here? Why isn't the original working for you? The `REQUEST_URI` variable holds the URL-path being requested, this has nothing do to with the site the user is coming _from_. The empty referer is only for when a user types a URL directly into the browser - or when a user supresses the `Referer` header in their browser or when a website supresses the sending of the `Referer` header using the referrer-policy (supported by all modern browsers). For added security (for want of a better word) an empty referer should be blocked (1st example).

Comment: @MrWhite sorry for not being clear - i just suggest the use of request_URI in order to solve my issue : when a user not coming from referrer he got a forbidden when accessing  https://your-domain.com BUT can access https://your-domain.com/page/ if he directly type the url in the browser - i would expect a forbiden message too in this last case and for all page in my website

Comment: Yes, you should be getting a forbidden response for direct requests to `your-domain.com/page/`, providing you are using the first version, without the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]` condition. If not then you are either seeing a cached response or there is a conflict with other directives. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: @MrWhite In fact your right that i added your conditions AFTER the ones below which are automatically generated when updating permalink - may be it's inside it we will found the light :

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: sorry i don't know how to order the code better than that - AND most of all thank you very much for the patience you show with me...really appreciated @MrWhite

Comment: You need to add these blocking directives _BEFORE_ all your existing directives, at the very top of the file, and importantly _BEFORE_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. Not _inside_ or _after_. If you place it after it will simply never get processed for a "WordPress" URL like `/page`. If you place it inside that code block then WordPress is likely to overwrite it. Order matters. (_Aside:_ You should edit your question to add any additional code snippets.)

Comment: thanks a lot for these precious informations and sorry for giving you only part of the code. If i may add a last things is there a way to exclude a single page from the directives so that this page can still be available even from non referrer - it would be a login page –