# htaccess restrict access to ALL pages but referrer

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, access-control

I managed to restrict access to my site using the `.htaccess` directives below. It works pretty well BUT I found that people other than referrer success to access direct page like `https://example.com/**pages**/` and from there can go back to home. How can I restrict to all site but the referrer (so all tree from my root URL).

```
# Serve everyone from specific-domain (and internal requests)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It works pretty well" when on the other hand you say it does _not_ work?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you want to achieve here. If you only want to allow access from a specific referrer _path_ - well then include that path in the value that you are checking %{HTTP_REFERER} against.

Comment: And what _is_ the referrer in those requests that do succeed?

Comment: (That this will not work correctly for any users who’s browser or an extension suppresses the referrer for privacy reasons, is clear to you?)

Comment: @arkascha i mean it works when trying to access https://your-domain.com if your don't come from https://specific-domain.com, you got a forbidden. But if you type an inside url like https://your-domain.com/pages/ you can access it with no message.

Comment: @CBroe yes i am aware that referrer can be cancelled by extension, but from now i haven't found other way to achieve the aim to restrict access to my whole website to only a specific domain referrer or n refferer... if you can advice more secure way to achieve so...you will be most welcome knowing that i am just a dev noob ;-)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to protect _against_ here, in what way a user accessing these pages in a different order or from a different starting point, would do any “harm” in the first place. But a proper solution would likely be using sessions.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply - it's not so much about harm an user can do than to force users to come from a certain domain origin where he will be authentified throuh a session AND restrict any other incoming access safe from this domain. hope the purpose is clearer like this

Comment: I suspect this is just a caching issue. The directives you posted will also catch requests to URLs that have a path component. So please, test with a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: @arkascha i already did with a "fresh" browser and private navigation with chrome and always the same issue - i saw somewhere something about restricting access to specific url : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sample-page [NC]   but i think i would need some wildcard for the whole site

Comment: You do have a wildcard. Which basically is what I said above. Look at your rules. If you do not know what they say, then you have a whole bunch of other issues.

Comment: @arkascha ok, i didn't notice your above message (sorry bout that) - then i still don't understand why when typing the direct URL in browser to access a specific page i don't get a forbidden message if the wildcard is set in the rules

Comment: So I repeat my initial question: what is the actual referred specified in those requests that do not get the expected response?

Comment: it would be the not allowed referred - i mean when accessing the inner page NOT from the referrer, i expect the response to be Forbidden - to test it i open a private session in my browser and when accessing https://your-domain.com i got a  good forbidden BUT if i type the URL https://your-domain.com/page/ it shows the page as if restrictions wasn't working

Comment: What do you mean "it would be"? Go and look what it _is_ ... That is what log files are for: to have precise data you can debug with instead of having to guess.

Comment: Also consider whether those rules may conflict with other rules you have in place. Maybe as part of some application logic...

Comment: so to go straight to the point and clarify things as much as i can : when i access the website from the referrer everything run smooth, no issue, no pb AND when i access the home page https://your-domain.com from A NO referrer i got a forbiden message (which is also what i expect) BUT if i just type in a URL directing to a page inside my site https://your_domain/page/ WITHOUT coming from a referrer then i DO get access to the page and THAT is not the behavior expected

Comment: Well, the usual course is to ask questions, collect details and therefore data that _help_ to answer a question. That process is caused _debugging_ ... just in case you stumble about that term in future... So the questions come _before_ an answer, whereas you appear to expect that people magically guess answers without having the required details. Anyway. Sorry I tried to help. Won't happen again ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411385/block-everyone-except-visitors-from-specific-referrer-with-htaccess), it seems you have been putting these directives in the wrong place. It is a WordPress site and the directives have been placed *after* the WordPress front-controller, ie. after the `# BEGIN WordPress` ... `# END WordPress` code block.

This is actually a very common mistake. But order matters.

By placing them at the end of the file they are simply never going to be processed for requests to `example.com/<wordpress-url>`, because the request has already been routed to the WordPress front-controller (`index.php`).

These blocking directives need to go at the very *top* of the `.htaccess` file. Importantly they must go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

You should NOT place these directives *inside* the WordPress code block since WordPress maintains this section and will likely overwrite any custom directives you place here.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive (which appears later in the file - the order of this directive does not matter). In fact, if there are multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the *last* directive wins and controls the entire file/context.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> is there a way to exclude a single page from the directives so that this page can still be available even from non referrer - it would be a login page

Yes, you can add an additional condition to the first block that checks for this URL. For example:

```
# Serve everyone from specific-domain (and internal requests)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI] ^/login$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Everybody else receives a forbidden 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

**UPDATE#2:**

However, since this is a WordPress site, you still need processing to continue to the front-controller (the `# BEGIN WordPress` section later in the file) in order to route the URLs. This would explain why you are seeing 404s for `/<page>` and other WordPress URLs despite the `Referer` presumably being set correctly.

To resolve this, change the `[L]` flag in the first `RewriteRule` to `[S=1]` (skip 1 rule), so instead of stopping further processing (the effect of the `L` / `last` flag), it simply skips the following rule that blocks access for everyone else. And continues on to the WordPress front-controller.

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Everybody else receives a forbidden 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Alternatively, you could reverse the logic...

```
# Block everyone from "other" domains except for specific URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI] !^/login$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Comment: thanks a lot for these precious informations and sorry for giving you only part of the code. If i may add a last things is there a way to exclude a single page from the directives so that this page can still be available even from non referrer - it would be a login page

Comment: Yes, you can add another condition to the first rule block to check the URL being requested. However, I'm not sure that this will work with the WordPress login page since WordPress usually issues an external redirect after login and this preserves the (possibly empty) `Referer`, so you may need to add more checks?

Comment: thanks for that too - i am not sure what "add more checks" imply but i will perform some tests and see where it leads .

Comment: in fact i tried the login restriction but without success so i share here the one which worked for me : RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} login [OR]    Thanks again for your help

Comment: it works ....BUT (always a but) : coming from a non referrer to authentication page (login) i can access the homepage but any page inside the site (https://your-domain/page/) return a NOT FOUND. Any idea why as with the condition i can access login and home but once connected i cannot browse the website. I tried to update permalink but it solved nothing.

Comment: dunno if you saw my last question or if you have (again) any time to spare me ?

Comment: Actually, since this is a WordPress site, you still need to permit requests to be routed by the WP front-controller (later in the file). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for all the help you gave me....i think all is good now....is there anything i can do to promote your help more than just "accept this answer" ? tell me i will do

Comment: i think i can imagine the answer but now that i allowed login page...someone who just click on above logo on the login page access directly to my home without authenticate first... i do believe there is no way to forbbid that as he is considered as being on the site when accessing to login page